# React - How to handle form submit for inputs in different components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form in a ReactJS project divided into various different components, the main component imports all the children component (which have the input boxes) and then also has the submit button:

How do I get all the components in synch so when I click enter or submit, I get in the main component's state the input from all the components inside? I have implemented submit on them but I am not able to get them all to submit at the same time.

I also tried using the HTML5 tag "form" and "id" to combine different components input but I wasn't able to do it.

```
class MainFormElement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input1data: "",
      input2data: "",
      input3data: "",
      ///...
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentWithInput1 />
        <ComponentWithInput2 />
        <ComponentWithInput3 />
        <button type="submit" form="mainForm">
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are already updating your state "input1Data, input2Data..." with your other components `<ComponentWithInput1 />` then you need your own `onSubmitHandler` function.

```html
class MainFormElement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      input1data: "",
      input2data: "",
      input3data: "",
      ///...
    };
  }
  
  onSubmitHandler(clickEvent) {
    const {input1data, input2data, input3data} = this.state
    
    const payload = [input1data, input2data, input3,data]
    
    doSomething(payload)
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentWithInput1 />
        <ComponentWithInput2 />
        <ComponentWithInput3 />
        <button onClick={this.onSubmitHandler} type="submit" form="mainForm">
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Take into account this is not a real "submit" action, this is simulating a submit but the browser won't treat it as such unless you have something like:

`<form><input type="submit"/></form>`

Comment: My problem was mainly updating the main component state with all the children components input (which is also their state) when I clicked the submit button, but seeing your code, it makes sense in this context that it doesn't really behave as a normal form.  I was able to pass all the components state to the main component inside the onChange() method in each component, not sure how efficient that is, feels really hacky but I think it will do

Comment: Passing the state up is the correct thing to do!

You can pass your own onChange handler to the children and inside the component just call "this.props.onChange()" and it'd work the same.

If you do this method your child input components should have no state and instead their value is passed down as props from MainFormElement

<ComponentWithInput1 value={this.state.inputValue1} />